# Ranking the months by amount of revenue generated SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables I am working with are

```
Orderdetails
ordernumber, productnumber, productcode, quantityordered, priceEach

Orders
ordernumber, orderdate (labeled as yyyy-mm-dd)
```

I understand getting the revenue `Sum( quantityOrdered * priceEach ) as TotalRevenue`.

Having difficulty grouping by month and joining the two tables.

Thank you

Comment: Is `orderdate` a text column or a `datetime` (or `date`)-typed column?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Not all DBMS use the ISO-compliant `EXTRACT` function to work with date values so we can't give you a solution that works with every DBMS.

Comment: Orderdate is a date column. Currently using MySQL 5.7 on DB FIddle. For an introduction sql class so sorry for the lack of detail on the question

Comment: What do you mean by "ranking"?

Comment: listing from highest to lowest

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would do:

```
select extract(year from o.orderdate) as yyyy,
       extract(month from o.orderdate) as mm,
       sum(ol.quantityOrdered * ol.priceEach) as total
from orders o join
     orderlines ol
     on o.ordernumber = ol.ordernumber
group by extract(year from o.orderdate), extract(month from o.orderdate)
order by yyyy, mm;
```

Databases are notoriously diverse in their support for date/time functions.  Many support the simpler `year()` and `month()` functions.  Many support other mechanisms for doing the same thing.

In MySQL, you can use the `year()` and `month()` functions:

```
select year(o.orderdate) as yyyy,
       month(o.orderdate) as mm,
       sum(ol.quantityOrdered * ol.priceEach) as total
from orders o join
     orderlines ol
     on o.ordernumber = ol.ordernumber
group by year(o.orderdate), 
order by yyyy, mm;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using T-SQL. It's straightforward to convert T-SQL to other SQL dialects.

First, let's get the total revenue of each order by grouping all `OrderDetails` by `OrderNumber` and `SUM`ing their value:

```
SELECT
    OrderNumber,
    SUM( QuantityOrdered * PriceEach ) AS OrderValue
FROM
    OrderDetails
GROUP BY
    OrderNumber
```

This gives us this output:

```
OrderNumber    OrderValue
          1        123.00
          2        456.00   
          3         50.00
          4       1024.00
```

Then `JOIN` this with `Orders` to get their `OrderDate`:

```
SELECT
    Orders.OrderNumber,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    COALESCE( ov.OrderValue, 0 ) AS OrderValue
FROM
    OrderDetails
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            OrderNumber,
            SUM( QuantityOrdered * PriceEach ) AS OrderValue
        FROM
            OrderDetails
        GROUP BY
           OrderNumber
    ) AS ov ON ov.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
```

This gives us this output:

```
OrderNumber   OrderDate  OrderValue
          1   2018-02-03     123.00
          2   2018-05-09     456.00   
          3   2018-02-04      50.00   
          4   2018-06-08    1024.00
```

Then we want to group rows by their month (a tuple of Year and Month) and find the `SUM` of `OrderValue` within each group. We can discard the `OrderNumber` column as it's no-longer needed. We can also add a `COUNT` too. Then `ORDER BY` the `SUM`

```
SELECT
    YEAR( Orders.OrderDate ) AS [Year],
    MONTH( Orders.OrderDate ) AS [Month],
    COUNT( * ) AS [OrderCount],
    SUM( COALESCE( ov.OrderValue, 0 ) ) AS RevenueInMonth 
FROM
    OrderDetails
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            OrderNumber,
            SUM( QuantityOrdered * PriceEach ) AS OrderValue
        FROM
            OrderDetails
        GROUP BY
           OrderNumber
    ) AS ov ON ov.OrderNumber = Orders.OrderNumber
GROUP BY
    YEAR( Orders.OrderDate ),
    MONTH( Orders.OrderDate )
ORDER BY
    RevenueInMonth DESC
```

This gives us this output:

```
Year    Month   OrderCount RevenueInMonth
2018        6            1        1024.00
2018        5            1         456.00
2018        2            2         173.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use grouping by `month` and `year` functions together as

```
select concat(month(orderdate),'/',year(orderdate)) as term,
       Sum( quantityOrdered * priceEach ) as TotalRevenue
  from Orders o
  left join Orderdetails d on o.ordernumber = d.ordernumber
 group by term;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UWR17539)

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` with a column defined in a same-level `SELECT` is a quirk of MySQL. Other DBMS require you to use an inner query.